# How to reason about an early return with a variable defined after

Tags: javascript

I was looking through the code of a JS library and saw this pattern:

```
function module() {
    function func() {
        //...
        definedAfter();
        //...
    }
    return func;
    var x = "....";
    function definedAfter() {
        //...
        console.log(x); //outputs undefined
        //...
    }
}
```

Google's Closure compiler flags the variable `x` as unused code, which seems reasonable, but the interesting part is that the variable is declared but with a value of `undefined` (due to hoisting).

Is this a bug in the library? Or is there some subtle behavior that is being exploited here? Maybe some type of optimization? Do different browsers act differently with regard to this example?

EDIT: I'm curious about the intent (bug or otherwise) of the original code, since it seems like `x` would always be `undefined`.

Comment: `x` should be `undefined`, not `null`...

Comment: Declaration order does not affect scope in JavaScript, but execution order rules should still prevail and it not be set, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 3):

I think you understand hoisting, but here's an explanation of what the function technically looks like:

```
function module() {
    function func() {
        //...
        definedAfter();
        //...
    }
    function definedAfter() {
        //...
        console.log(x); //outputs undefined
        //...
    }
    var x;
    return func;
    x = "....";
}
```

(I'm not sure of the actual final order of the things being hoisted, but I don't think it's important)

So the final `x = "....";` line will never be executed, but `x` will still be declared (as `undefined`), and is accessible by the inner function scopes.

So I have to say the library has a "bug" in the sense that the line that sets `x` as "...." will never be reached and does nothing.

Comment: Do you know of any Browser (IE6 or IE7, specifically) variation in that behavior? The value of x actually is related to some IE6/7 specific stuff, so It just led me to wonder if it's broken or IE6/7 just works differently. (I don't particularly care about supporting IE6/7, just curious about the intent)

Comment: @Andrew I don't think so. It's a different story when `x` is a global variable. But being declared locally, there shouldn't be any variation in that behavior. If `x` is global or anything like that, look at svidgen's answer to understand some things

Answer (score 1):

In line with Benn Flynn's comment, the parser pre-scans and/or compiles code before it's actually executed. Hence, it detects variable scope from any line, executed or not, in your block.

Run this in your browser's console:

```
var f = function() {
  // we haven't defined a local x yet, so we're tempted to think
  // that this line is mucking with window.x
  x = 1;
  console.log(x, window.x);
  return;

  // and we're tempted to think this line is never seen, because it
  // occurs after the return. but, it ensures that x is local, not global.
  var x = 2;
};
f();
```

In your console you'll see something like this:

```
1 undefined
```

And afterwards, `window.x` doesn't exist. It hasn't been referred to anywhere, thanks to our declaration -- whether the assignment portion of the declaration is necessary, I'm not sure. It shouldn't be. But, I wouldn't be surprised to learn that some version of IE ignores the declaration if the assignment isn't also present.

Compare it to this:

```
var f = function() {
  x = 1;
  console.log(x, window.x);
  return;
  x = 2;  // this line truly does nothing.
};
f();
```

We see this in the console:

```
1 1
```

And afterwards, `windows.x` is `1`.

It's also notable that `definedAfter()` works correctly because it's not written in variable-assignment form:

```
// this puts definedAfter in scope, but it's undefined unless this line is
// actually executed
var definedAfter = function() { /* whatever */ }
```

Instead, it's written in "function declarative" form, which doesn't get "executed."

```
function definedAfter() { /* whatever */ }
```

Rather, the compiler sees it during compilation and says, "oh, this function is part of the scope." This difference affords you the ability in the variable-assignment syntax to control precisely when your functions are available for use. And in function-declarative form, the ability to define your functions anywhere without worrying about execution order.

Comment: Why are you complicating things by throwing in global variables? It's nice to point out what omitting of `var` at the end of the function does, but it has nothing to do with the reason why `x` is `undefined`. It's called variable hoisting.

Comment: @Ian What it's called is somewhat irrelevant. The whole purpose of the declaration is to take x out of the global scope. Hence, talking about the impact on global scope relevant ...

Comment: Although you are correct about global scope, It's not related to the behavior I'm seeing here, mostly about the value part of the local `x` and why would it be used that way (assuming that it would always be `undefined`)

Comment: @Andrew I'd wager the assignment part (= "whatever") was probably added by a paranoid developer -- or maybe one who knows of some minor revision of some browser(s) that ignore variable declaration with "missing" assignments.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a bug in the library. Yet, it's not the most elegant code.

There are two things you need to know to understand it better

1) The meaning of hoisting 
2) the difference between Function expressions and Function declarations is subtle and yes different browsers act differently.

(for the latter see: http://kangax.github.io/nfe)

cheers